# Where is the mesh?

Tags: mesh

I don't see my mesh anymore, only the bones.
I don't remember how that happened.

How could I make it visible again?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Mesh scale is 0.025, make it bigger to see it
[image]

Comment: Where do you change that, please? Ah, I got it: PCL3-> Orange dot -> Scale